# How to create another columns by selecting only the even rows of the original one?

Tags: r, dataframe

This is my dataframe:

```
 df = data.frame(Column1 = c(0.6356695,0.8892128,1.6114966,1.8713276,1.8060065,2.2590467,1.9850608,2.8007610,1.5946618,2.7254078,0.4813844,1.8026726,0.3588233,1.3347234))

  Column1
1  0.6356695
2  0.8892128
3  1.6114966
4  1.8713276
5  1.8060065
6  2.2590467
7  1.9850608
8  2.8007610
9  1.5946618
10 2.7254078
11 0.4813844
12 1.8026726
13 0.3588233
14 1.3347234
```

I would like to create another column by extracting only the even rows from *Column1* (2, 4, 6,.., 14) and at the same time delete from *Column1* this rows.

The final output should look like:

```
    Column1     Column2 
1  0.6356695    0.8892128
2  1.6114966    1.8713276
3  1.8060065    2.2590467
4  1.9850608    2.8007610
5  1.5946618    2.7254078
6 0.4813844    1.8026726
7 0.3588233    1.3347234
```

I did this in several steps but I am sure that some of you could do this compactly and more efficiently (I tried to do it in one shot myself as well by using `mutate` but not successfull).

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1) logical recycling** We can use the fact that logicals recycle:

```
data.frame(Column1 = df[c(TRUE, FALSE), ], Column2 = df[c(FALSE, TRUE), ])
```

giving:

```
    Column1   Column2
1 0.6356695 0.8892128
2 1.6114966 1.8713276
3 1.8060065 2.2590467
4 1.9850608 2.8007610
5 1.5946618 2.7254078
6 0.4813844 1.8026726
7 0.3588233 1.3347234
```

This can also be written:

```
data.frame(Column1 = df[!0:1, ], Column2 = df[!1:0, ])
```

**2) reshaped matrix** Another way is to reshape the column into a matrix:

```
nms <- c("Column1", "Column2")
m <- matrix(df$Column1,, 2, byrow = TRUE, dimnames = list(NULL, nms))
as.data.frame(m)
```

**3) rollapply**  We can take two elements at a time using rollapply, convert that to data.frame and add the column names.  `nms` is from (2).

```
library(zoo)

r <- rollapply(df$Column1, 2, by = 2, c)
setNames(as.data.frame(r), nms)
```

**4) embed** We can manipulate the output of embed into the required form.  `nms` is from (2).

```
e <- embed(df$Column1, 2)[c(TRUE, FALSE), 2:1]
setNames(as.data.frame(e), nms)
```

Comment: wow! Never seen this around, beautiful code. Thanks so much! I will mark it as correct when SO allows me to do so.

Answer (score 2):

A method using `unstack`:

```
df$x <- c("Column1", "Column2")
unstack(df, Column1 ~ x)

#     Column1   Column2
# 1 0.6356695 0.8892128
# 2 1.6114966 1.8713276
# 3 1.8060065 2.2590467
# 4 1.9850608 2.8007610
# 5 1.5946618 2.7254078
# 6 0.4813844 1.8026726
# 7 0.3588233 1.3347234
```

Answer (score 2):

Another `base R` possibility could be:

```
setNames(cbind.data.frame(split(df, 1:nrow(df) %% 2 == 0)), 
         c("Column1", "Column2"))

     Column1   Column2
1  0.6356695 0.8892128
3  1.6114966 1.8713276
5  1.8060065 2.2590467
7  1.9850608 2.8007610
9  1.5946618 2.7254078
11 0.4813844 1.8026726
13 0.3588233 1.3347234
```

Comment: All the answers are very very good. I have learnt a lot. Thanks you all. I marked the first who commented but you all deserved more points than I could give. Thanks for your help!